# What invocation will use LZMA to compress tar output on my Mac (OSX 10.12.x)?

Tags: tar, compression, lzma

I've tried several invocations of the OEM tar to create LZMA-compressed tarballs. More specifically, I tried:

```
tar -c -f --lzma Windows\ 7.vmwarevm.tar.lzma Windows\ 7.vmwarevm
```

My efforts created an archive with filename `--lzma`, and tar complained of `Windows 7.vmwarevm.tar.lzma`: `Cannot stat: No such file or directory`, probably for the same reason: `--lzma` was taken as the filename of the archive to be created, and consequently the actual intended archive name was taken to be the first in a list of arguments to include in the archive.

I thought after some searching that MacOS had not included it in the provided options, and built GNU tar from scratch, storing it under another name in `/usr/local/bin`. However, my efforts to use the above invocation with the renamed and newly built `tar` had the same effect: I was building an archive in `--lzma`.

My computer has a seemingly working `/usr/local/bin/lzma`.

What invocation(s) should I use, perhaps piping `tar` to `lzma` and perhaps in a script to do the work of "tar czf foo.tgz foo", but uses `lzma` instead of `gzip` for compression?

Comment: Thank you; please restate your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `tar`, the [first word after `-f` is the output filename](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html). In your case, switching the order of options might be enough:

```
tar -c --lzma -f foo.tar.lzma sourcefile(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with drewbenn,

it might also work in case to

```
tar c files folders/ | lzma --options-here > foo.tar.lzma
```

This might also work for in case if you want to use any parallel compressors to speed up the thing.